# Substitute a value in an array wherever a certain key appears

Tags: php, arrays, linux

I have a multilevel JSON object with a lot of data.
the key "id" appears in many places and depths.
I need to find all the "id" keys, get the relevant value and substitute it (doing a lookup)

So far I have written this code:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);


function getElement($p, $v) {
    echo "$p => $v\n";
    
}


function arrayFind($path, $a) {

    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        // echo "$k\n";
        if (is_array($v)){
            // echo "$k\n";
            if ($path == "")    $p = $k;
            else                $p = $path . "|" . $k;
                
            arrayFind($p ,$v);
        } else {
            if ($k === "id") {
                // echo "$path.$k => $v\n";
                getElement($path . "|" . $k,  $v);
            }
        }
    }
    
}


arrayFind("", $arr);
```

And it is successfully giving me output of all the id's it found with the relevant values...

```
0|id => 1141159925645373
1|id => 1141159925645374
1|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579912
2|id => 1141159925645376
2|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579911
3|id => 1141159925645377
3|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579911
4|id => 1141159925645379
4|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579910
5|id => 1141159925645380
5|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579911
6|id => 1141159925645381
6|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579912

.. etc..
```

So now I need to turn, for example

```
6|staffAssignments|0|ids|0|id => 1141168515579912
```

into :

```
$arr[6]["staffAssignments"][0]["ids"][0]["id"] = "**newValue**"
```

in order to access the array and change the relative value

But how do I turn a string into an array key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ?

```
function search_and_replace(&$array, $searchedKey, $searchedValue,$newValue)
{
    array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function (&$value,$key) use($searchedKey,$searchedValue,$newValue) {
        if ($key===$searchedKey && $value===$searchedValue) {
            $value = $newValue;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Amazing.. thank you so much.. I didnt consider passing by reference ...

Comment: @user3231130 if this solve your problem, can you please mark my post as a solution ! Thank you in advance !

Comment: I Would LOVE to .. just dont see how to!

Comment: @user3231130 you should have a tick in the left side of my answer (bellow the arrows). You can just click on it ^^